# I can't understand how do 'global`s work in TypeScript/NodeJS and what is their difference?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, global, ts-jest

I am reading a code like below:

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import request from "supertest";
import { app } from "../app";

declare global {
  function signin(): Promise<string[]>;
}

let mongo: any;

beforeAll(async () => {
  process.env.JWT_KEY = "asdfasdf";
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

  const mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const mongoUri = mongo.getUri();

  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {});
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  if (mongo) {
    await mongo.stop();
  }
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

global.signin = async () => {
  const email = "test@test.com";
  const password = "password";

  const response = await request(app)
    .post("/api/users/signup")
    .send({
      email,
      password,
    })
    .expect(201);

  const cookie = response.get("Set-Cookie");

  return cookie;
};
```

I can't understand the purpose of `global.signin` function and how does it work? I guess it has something to do with `Jest` but as long as I know the Jest codes should be inside the `__test__` folder with the same file name and `.test.ts` extension. But the above function is defined and used inside the `setup.ts` file in the root of the application.

I also see some codes like following:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      currentUser?: UserPayload;
    }
  }
}
```

In some `.ts` files of the project as well that I am not sure are these `global` variables the same as the other `global`s I mentioned above or these are different things? I am interested to know how this `global` variables work as well?

Comment: someone wanted to be able to call `signin()` from any file without imports, I wouldn't advise doing that but whatever you define on `global` simply exists globally. Just like you can do `setTimeout()` without having to import anything specific. `global` is node's version of brower's `window` (and both being replaced by `globalThis` to have a common standard). If `thing` is nothing that exists in the current local scope (like a `let` variable, an import, ..) node will lookup `global.thing` and take that instead.

Comment: @zapl: Are globals in both codes the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript/TypeScript running in node will try to resolve anything it can't find in the current local scope in `global` (the same way a browser would look in `window`). Any function or variable you can access globally (e.g. `setTimeout()`), can also be accessed with `global.` as prefix. It just makes it explicit.

What happens in your code are two things:

```
declare global {
  function signin(): Promise<string[]>;
}
```

Here it tells typescript's type system that the `global` object also has a function called `signin`. This part is <s>not required but it makes sense</s> required for typescript to allow you to access / define that function, in JavaScript you simply define it.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html has some details how `declare` works.

```
global.signin = async () => {
   // code ...
};
```

And here it is actually added to the global object.

In JavaScript non strict mode you could even write (notice the lack of `var`/`let`/`const`/`global.`)

```
signin = async () => {
   // code ...
};
```

I don't see `signin` getting used anywhere in that code so the reason for it is unclear to me. As long as the file that defines it gets loaded you can  call the function simply by referring to it as `signin()`. The `global.` is added implicitly.

The purpose of

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      currentUser?: UserPayload;
    }
  }
}
```

is more practical, in express you may want to add properties to your requests that get added by middleware. By declaring that the Express Request has a property called `currentUser` you get to do

```
app.get((req, res) => {
   const user: UserPayload = req.currentUser
   ...
})
```

without typescript complaining about an unknown property.
More on that for example https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/

Comment: Thank you so much for the complete explanation. May I ask if there is any difference where you declare/define global? I mean in which file of the project or after which functions?

Comment: @GoodMan The declare part needs to be "loaded" in your current scope so typescript allows you access to variables/functions it otherwise claims do not exist. A useful place in a project would be a dedicated "types" directory (see that logrocket article) because you can set it explicitly in tsconfig.json and define all the types you need to access without relying on importing declarations. Where you actually modifies the global object is only important when it comes to order of execution. Most likely you want to add it as early as possible, like from the initial entry (app) ts.

Answer (score 2):

The piece of code you shared is making use of global augmentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation

```
// Hint typescript that your global object will have a custom signin function
declare global {
  function signin(): Promise<string[]>;
}

// Assign value to global.signin
global.signin = async () => { /* implementation */ };
```

Likely one or multiple modules ("mongoose", "supertest", "../app") imported by the test file is using global.signin (or window.signin) at some point (or maybe one of their nested imports is => look for "signin(" in the project). Thus for testing purposes, global.signin needed to be mocked. However just adding `global.signin = something` would raise a typescript error, because signin is not a standard global variable. This is where `declare global` comes into play. It hints typescript that in your particular context, a `signin` function is expected to exist in global scope.